# Counting on Nested Models in Rails Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm displaying a map and need the data to be formatted as follow:

```
{"US" => 3, "UK" => 7, "FR" => 0}
```

Where "US" is a country.code and 3 a count of visits
Also, I have 3 tables

| Country | Price | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | price_id |
| code | country_id |  |

I'm trying to count every visits for each country code but the best I have is every visits for each country_id, like so `Visit.joins(:price).group('prices.country_id').count` resulting in:

```
{1 => 3, 2 => 7, 3 => 0}
```

How I can "bring" the country.code in the result in one single query?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be

```rb
Visit
  .joins(price: :country)
  .group('prices.country_id, countries.code')
  .select('countries.code, count(countries.code)')
```